Fubini's theorem in Stochastic Integral
The short rate under the Merton model is
$r_t = r_s + \theta (t - s) + \sigma \int_s^t d w_u$
Now we integrate above to get bond price from s to T
$\int_s^T r_t \, dt = \int_s^T r_s \, dt + \theta \int_s^T (t - s) \, dt + \sigma \int_s^T \int_s^t d w_u \, dt$
This simplifies to below.
$=r_s (T - s) + \theta \int_s^T t \, dt - \theta s \int_s^T dt + \sigma \int_s^T \int_u^T d w_u \, dt$
Order of integration is changed for the last double integral. I am not able to understand the order change using Fubini's theorem. Though the order is changed the outer integral bound remains same.
Any explanation on this order change would be greatly appreciated!

The integral $\int_s^T\int_s^t\,dw_u\,dt$ does definitely not simplify to $\int_s^T\int_s^{\color{red}T}\,dw_u\,dt\,.$
The former is $\int_s^Tw_t-w_s\,dt$ and the latter is $\int_s^Tw_{\color{red}T}-w_s\,dt=(w_{\color{red}T}-w_s)(T-s)\,.$ Fubini tells us (just as in ordinary calculus) since the region of integration is $s<u<t<T$ that
\begin{align}
&\int_s^T\int_s^t\,dw_u\,dt=\int_s^T\int_u^T\,dt\,dw_u=\underbrace{\int_s^T(T-u)\,dw_u}=T(w_T-w_s)-\int_s^Tu\,dw_u\,.
\end{align}
The underbraced form is the one that we usually find in the  literature and imho the most neat one.

That was typo in the second integral actually. Apologies for that. I have edited the question. Can you please explain this little bit in detail. Thanks.

The Stochastic Fubini Theorem allows to exchange $dw_u$ and $dt,.$ The integral bounds after change follow (as I said from) the region of integration $s<u<t<T$ just like in ordinary calculus. If you don't understand this perhaps drawing a picture helps. I don't know what further explanations I should give. You need to practice.
